# uploading file to folder on website via PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I would like to have the user upload a pdf to a folder on my website. (note:this is for learning purposes, so security is not necessary) The code I have below does not do echo a response when submitted.  The folder I would like to have the pdf uploaded to is in the same directory as the php script, is it possible I'm incorrectly referencing that folder?  I appreciate it.

```
<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Email:<br /> <input type = "text" name="email" value=""/><br />
Resume:<br /><input type = "file" name="resume" value=""/><br />
<p><input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Submit Resume" /></p>
</form>


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    define ("FILEREPOSITORY","./resume/");

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) {
        if ($_FILES['resume']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
            echo "<p>Resume must be in PDF Format.</p>";
        }
    }else {
        $name = $_POST['email'];

        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], FILEREPOSITORY."/$name.pdf");

        if ($result == 1) {
            echo "<p>File successfully uploaded.</p>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>There was a problem uploading the file.</p>";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have spaces between attribute names and their values. `type = "text"` should be `type="text"`.

Comment: If you're posting a form to the *exact same* URL, omit the action. It will default to the request URI used to fetch the page.

Comment: @Kenaniah That doesn't actually matter (for your first comment, and your second one).

Comment: Are you sure your permissions are set alright on your folder? This is usually the biggest problem :) If you use a remote server, with FTP, you can usually adjust your permissions with a client like Filezilla, set it to 777 (as security is optional for your case)

Comment: @Kenaniah You need the action attribute, or else it's not valid HTML.

Comment: @jli, I never said it was necessary. Just some minor tips.

Comment: @Kenaniah Well the first comment might hold some truth, but it's just a preference thing. The second comment is plain wrong for valid HTML.

Comment: @jValdron, allow me to qualify your statement by saying it's required in HTML 4, but no longer required in HTML 5.

Comment: permissions to the folder are now set to 777.  Still nothing happens.

Comment: Not an answer, but just a comment: Depending on the OS of your server it's not necessarily a good idea to use email as a file name, what with the dot in it. Should be fine on linux, but not sure how it's gonna behave if you try to open .com.pdf on windows machine.

Comment: @AR Good point.  I'm going to use single words to check if that's the case.

Comment: @AR Windows will open a PDF just fine, it doesn't check the mime type like most of the GUIs on Linux, it just gets the extension, which is considered the content after the last dot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a logical error. Your `else` statement should be part of the inner `if` statement -- not the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

would suggest you check the permissions for the upload folder and the max size for file uploading in your php.ini... its happened to me many times uploading a file exceeding the limits and not getting an error message.. also the logic of your if else doesn't match as suggested by your previous post..

Answer (score 0):

IT would be of great help to give the error you receive.

```
move_uploaded_file()
```

only works if you have the rights to write to the destination folder.